# tracemalloc in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks

I am trying to use Python's `tracemalloc` module and copied the `display_top` function from the [API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#tracemalloc.Statistic.traceback). The output can be seen below, which is not super helpful:

```
 #1: collections/__init__.py:366: 85.6 KiB
  exec(class_definition, namespace)

 #2: python3.4/ast.py:55: 83.9 KiB
   return tuple(map(_convert,
```

What I really want to see is where in my application these functions are invoked from. So, I'd really like to see the oldest frame as opposed to the most recent frame. Is this even the correct approach though?

I have tried `tracemalloc.start(25)` so that it stores up to 25 frames. 
But if I check `len(stat.traceback)`, it is 1! So, I can only print the most recent frame, which is not so useful.

```
def display_top(self, snapshot, group_by="lineno",  limit=_NUM_MEMORY_BLOCKS):
    snapshot = snapshot.filter_traces((
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"),
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<unknown>"),
    ))
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics(group_by)

    for index, stat in enumerate(top_stats[:limit], 1):
        # Ideally, I want to print all frames in traceback. 
        # But length of the traceback is somehow always 1 !!
        frame = stat.traceback[0] 
        # replace "/path/to/module/file.py" with "module/file.py"
        filename = os.sep.join(frame.filename.split(os.sep)[-2:])
        log.debug("#%s: %s:%s: %.1f KiB", index, filename, frame.lineno, stat.size / 1024)
        line = linecache.getline(frame.filename, frame.lineno).strip()
        if line:
            log.debug("    %s", line)

    other = top_stats[limit:]
    if other:
        size = sum(stat.size for stat in other)
        log.debug("%s other: %.1f KiB", len(other), size / 1024)
    total = sum(stat.size for stat in top_stats)
    log.debug("Total allocated size: %.1f KiB", total / 1024)
```

Comment: I think you want to see the newest frame and, indeed, a couple of the older ones to see from where the allocation has been invoked, much like a "normal" stack trace from a crash. I have the exact same problem as you and when I find a solution, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `snapshot.statistics`, you need to pass `'traceback'` instead of `'lineno'`; in that case `tracemalloc.start(25)` will indeed store 25 frames, which you can show e.g. like this: `print('\n'.join(stat.traceback.format()))`